# Unit tests file IO java

Tags: java, unit-testing, io

I am trying to write a unit tests on a class that dynamically creates java classes using data from XLS file. All the write methods I used are private. I have one public method in the same class that makes a call to all these private write methods. Can some one tell me how to write unit tests for this scenario.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Either you can make the methods package local, or you can test them by calling the public methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by two ways :

By reflection, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes) :

```
Method method = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, argClasses);
method.setAccessible(true);
return method.invoke(targetObject, argObjects);
```

Or you cant use PowerMock if you want to mock private methods.

Answer (score 1):

`Private` methods should be used internally in the `class`, and hence you don't need to test them, because by testing the public ones, your are indirectly  testing the private ones. Unless they are never used, then you delete them so you don't have them in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I created a new thread to explain this scenario in more detail...
Really appreciate your time...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874254/test-if-the-returned-string-has-java-class